# Indexes for optimising SQL Joins in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, inner-join

Given the below query

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON (A.b_id = B.id) 
WHERE (A.user_id = 'XXX' AND B.provider_id = 'XXX' AND A.type = 'PENDING') 
ORDER BY A.created_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The variable values in the query are `A.user_id` and `B.provider_id`,  the type is always queried on `'PENDING'`.

I am planning to add a `compound` + `partial` index on A
`A(user_id, created_at) where type = 'PENDING'`

Also the number of records in A >> B.

Given `A.user_id`, `B.provider_id`, `A.b_id` all are foreign keys. Is there any way I can optimize the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are doing an inner join, I would first express the query as follows, with the join in the opposite direction:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON A.b_id = B.id
WHERE A.user_id = 'XXX' AND A.type = 'PENDING' AND
      B.provider_id = 'XXX'
ORDER BY
    A.created_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Then I would add the following index to the `A` table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_a ON A (user_id, type, created_at, b_id);
```

This four column index should cover the join from `B` to `A`, as well as the `WHERE` clause and also the `ORDER BY` sort at the end of the query.  Note that we could probably also have left the query with the join order as you originally wrote above, and this index could still be used.

Comment: If you are driving at a nested loop join, you should also index `b(id)`. The columns are in the wrong order: `b_id` should be last or not there at all.

Comment: The join order won't change a thing in terms of the execution plan or performance

Comment: Can i use a partial index on 'PENDING' since i know I will be only quering on that.

`CREATE INDEX idx_a ON A (user_id, created_at, b_id) where type = 'PENDING';`

Comment: Try it out and then check the execution plan.

Comment: It does improve the performance slightly, I think when the data size is large the difference can be seen since the index size will be less in case of partial index.